# Can SVG <title> content line-break using &#10; entity (or something else)?

Tags: html, svg, mouseover, title, line-breaks

I'm trying to line-break content in a mouseover ("tooltip"), that is placed into an SVG document DOM using the `<title>` child element.

Firefox seems to respect this and place a line-break where I want it.  IE11, however does not.  Have not tried other browsers.

The XSL that gens this looks like,

```
<title><xsl:value-of select="concat('foo','&#10;','bar')"/></title>
```

I've also tried `<br/>` with no luck.

The document is served to the browser as a "pure SVG" document, that is, the root element is `<svg>`.  I'm using HTML5 DOCTYPE header, nothing intentionally backwards compatible there.

Thank you, stackoverflow friends!

Comment: add a fiddle with your question it will be easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: Apologies Skynet, I have no suitable hosting to do that.  I'm not a fiddler, yet.  It's pretty straightforward stuff, just how the <title> tag handles stuff.

Comment: It's ok, I'm try to extend quality of your question by doing such you would expect more quality responses.

Comment: Yeah, no doubt Skynet.  I understand what you're saying.  If I have time to figure something out I'll post here.  Thanks!

Comment: Line breaks are supposed to work as you have them. IE does not implement support for this though as you have discovered. I don't really know what else you want us to say. What you have is an observation rather than a question.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was 1. asking if everyone else has observed the behavior in this way, and 2. if there's some work around folks have found.  You did confirm that IE is an outlyer, which is helpful, so thanks for that.

Comment: It's possible to have multiline tooltips, but it is implemented differently in different browsers due to differences between SVG and HTML title tooltips (attribute vs text content) and whitespace handling.  [Complete discussion and links to fiddles in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25690802/3128209).  I'm going to mark this a duplicate; if that Q&A doesn't address your issues, please edit to focus the question on the remaining issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tooltip to display in two separate lines not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626422/tooltip-to-display-in-two-separate-lines-not-working-in-firefox)