# d3 node-tooltip values multi-line

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, d3.js

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";  })
.on("click", click)
.on("mouseover",function (d){       
    if(d.name=="Purchased"){                  
        jQuery.getJSON("RequestHandler?usercommand=jsoncompany&subcommand=propCount&useraction=d3Tree_frm&mgmtId="+d.id+"&type="+d.name, function(json){
            var count=JSON.stringify(json.prop_purchased_count);                      
            result="Purchased Property :"+count;                                
        });
    }   
    var g = d3.select(this);              
    var info = g.append("text")
        .classed('info', true)
        .attr('x', 30)
        .attr('y', 30)         
        .text(result);   //result="Amount":200\n"Amount":300\n"Amount":400  
})
.on("mouseout", function() {      
    d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove();
});
```

//result="Amount":200\n"Amount":300\n"Amount":400
 i want to display tooltip such that after \n it appears in a new line within that tooltip.

How to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where else apart from in `if(d.name=="Purchased")` is `result` being set? As currently it should be reading `Purchased Property : ...` rather than `Amount:...`

Comment: Also `getJSON` is asynchronous so you will probably be executing the adding of `.text(result)` before you can manipulate the result in the `getJSON` callback.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker yes in else part Amount is set

Comment: Please show all your code, even better would be a working jsfiddle

Comment: @RobSchmuecker my problem is that i get result "Amount":200\n"Amount":300\n"Amount":400 so instead of \n it must appear in next line within that tooltip

Comment: I know that but since you're not showing the code where that is being set it is hard to help you!

Comment: var g = d3.select(this);              
    var info = g.append("text")
        .classed('info', true)
        .attr('x', 30)
        .attr('y', 30)         
        .text(result);

Answer (score 1):

I can see `result` being set in the code you posted, however what we cannot see is where `result` is being set to get the content you are 'saying' it contains.  That way we could help you interpret the application of these proven recommendations a lot better.  But in anycase, have a look at these resources to help you in your quest.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

[How to dynamically display a multiline text in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791143/how-to-dynamically-display-a-multiline-text-in-d3-js)

Answer (score 0):

In the else part add "Amount:"+ count + "\n" while you are concatenating the newline